# Se string começar com "www" inserir automaticamente "https://"

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte

Para o usuário não precisar digitar `https://` estou tentando fazer com que, quando o texto do `EditText` começar com `www.` vai automaticamente inserir o `https://`

Eu tentei:

```
 if (!s_url.startsWith("www.")) {
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://"+s_url);
 }
```

Mas sem sucesso.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

### Código:

```
final String s_url = editText_url.getText().toString();
final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
final EditText editText_url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_url);
```

---

```
//IME Action
    editText_url.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = true;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                myWebView.loadUrl(editText_url.getText().toString());
                if (!s_url.startsWith("www.")) {
                    myWebView.loadUrl("http://"+s_url);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

---

Comment: Você consegue editar o virtual host do seu servidor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando o [operador de negação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1k6w8551.aspx) `!`, por isso não funciona do modo que você espera.

```
 if (!s_url.startsWith("www.")) {
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://" + s_url);
 }
```

A segunda linha só entra em ação quando o conteúdo de `s_url` não começa com `www.`.

Comment: Obrigado ^^,so era tirar o `!`. PS: acabei usando `editText_url.getText().toString().startsWith("www."))` no lugar da var `s_url` mas creio que as duas funcionem do mesmo modo